# How to find generator $g$ in a cyclic group?

Tags: random-number-generator, diffie-hellman, modular-arithmetic

As generator $g$ is used in DH how do you find a combination of prime $p$ and $g$? eg: if we choose $p=23$ and its generator is $7$ (given in the book) how do we find the generator?

Answer (score 15):

Mike gave you the answer for the specific question you asked.  I'll try to give you an answer to the question you should have asked:

> For Diffie-Hellman, what criteria should I use to select a secure $p$ and $g$?

This question is important, because not every large cyclic group is actually secure.  It turns out that, for the group $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, the factorization of $p-1$ is critical.

If $p-1$ has a factor $q$, and $g^{(p-1)/q} \ne 1$, then given $g$ and $g^x \bmod p$, we can determine $x \bmod q$ in $O(\sqrt{q})$ time.

What does this mean?  Well, if we pick a $p$ where $p-1$ has a bunch of small factors $q_1, q_2, q_3$, and we give $g$ to be a primitive element (so $g^{(p-1)/q} \ne 1$ for any $q > 1$), then we transmit $g^x \bmod p$ as a part of the DH exchange, the attacker can efficiently derive $x \bmod q_1q_2q_3$; we're effectively giving him $\log_2 q_1q_2q_3$ bits of our secret exponent.  This means that, with a random prime $p$ and either a random $g$, or a primitive $g$, we have a good possibility of leaking quite a bit of information.

So, what do we do?  Well, first of all, we make sure that $p-1$ has a large prime factor $q$ that we know.  There are two common practices:

- Select a prime $p$ with $(p-1)/2$ prime as well (often called a [safe prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime)).  If we do that, then $q = (p-1)/2$ is certainly large enough (assuming $p$ is large enough).
- Select a prime value $q$ (perhaps 256 to 512 bits), and then search for a large prime $p = kq + 1$ (perhaps 1024 to 2048 bits).  This is called a [Schnorr prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group)

Once we have our values $p$ and $q$, we then select a generator $g$ that is within the subgroup of size $q$.  Members of this subgroup have the property that $g^{(p-1)/r} = 1$ for any factors $r$ of $p-1$ other than $q$ (and $p-1$ itself), hence the above observation does not apply.

One easy way of selecting a random generator is to select a random value $h$ between 2 and $p-1$, and compute $h^{(p-1)/q} \bmod p$; if that value is not 1 (and with high probability, it won't be), then $h^{(p-1)/q} \bmod p$ is your random generator.

An alternative method of finding a generator $g$: if you selected a safe prime, and if your safe prime also satisfied the condition $p = 7 \bmod 8$, then the value $g=2$ will always be a generator for the group of size $q$.  It won't obviously be a random generator, however, we can also show that, with a safe prime, if you can solve the computational Diffie-Hellman problem with $g=2$, you can solve it with any $g$ (with a polynomial number of queries), hence $g=2$ cannot be weak.

Comment: There's something that seems confusing in your answer and I hope you can clarify it. If we select a safe prime $p=2q+1$ and we now want to select a generator $g$ within the subgroup of size $q$, you suggest to take a random value $h$ between $2$ and $p-1$ and then compute $h^{(p-1)/q} \mod p$, which would be the same as computing $h^2 \mod p$. If the result of this is not $1$ this definitely means that $h$ is not a generator of the subgroup of order $2$, but this doesn't necessarily mean that it's a generator of the one of order $q$, we still would have to check that $h^q=1 \mod p$, don't we?

Comment: @LRM: you misunderstood the pronoun (and I fixed the answer to be clearer); compute $h^2$, and if this is not 1, then $h^2$ is your generator (not $h$ -- I used "it's", and it wasn't clear which that referred to).  Then, we needn't bother to check if $(h^2)^q = 1$, as that's $h^{2q} = h^{p-1}$, and Fermat's Little Theorem says that'll be 1.

Comment: Oh right, now everything makes sense! So if we have that $h^2 \mod p \neq 1$, then this is at the same time telling us that $h^2$ is a quadratic residue and therefore must be in the subgroup of order $q$. Thanks a lot for you clarification and for having edited your answer.

Comment: Is $g^{(p-1)/r} \neq 1$ the same as checking whether $g^q mod p = -1$?. I believe the first equation is from Fermat's little theorem. The second one is Euler's criterion.

Comment: @omnomnom; no, they're not the same; if $g^{(p-1)/r} \ne 1$, then the size of the subgroup that $g$ generates has $r$ as a factor (assuming $r$ is a divisor of $p-1$).  In contrast, if $g^q \bmod p = -1$, then the size of the subgroup that $g$ generates is either $2$ or $2q$ (assuming $q$ is prime)

Comment: $g^{(p-1)/r} = 1$ - could you please explain where does this equation come from?

Comment: @omnomnom: the context is that $g$ is an element of order $q$; that is, $g^q = 1$.  $q$ is a prime divisor of $p-1$, hence for any other prime divisor $r$ of $p-1$, $(p-1)/r$ is a multiple of $q$, that is, $(p-1)/r = kq$ for some integer $k$.  So, $g^{(p-1)/r} = g^{kq} = (g^q)^k = 1^k = 1$

Comment: Thank you @poncho, it's now clear to me where does $g^{(p-1)/r}$ come from. Still, I don't understand why do we check $g^{(p-1)/q}$. Could you please clarify?

Comment: I mention $g^{(p-1)/q}$ in two different contexts; it's not clear which you are asking about.  In the first context (paragraph that starts with "What does this mean? Well, if we pick a $p$ where $p-1$ has a bunch of small factors"; in this context, $q$ is a small prime, and this tells us when the attacker can compute $x \bmod q$ from $g^x \bmod p$.  In the second context (paragraph "One easy way of selecting a random generator…"), well, we don't check the value, we use that value (if it's not one, then it's the generator we're looking for)

Comment: @poncho why is exactly `log2123` bites leaked here?

Comment: @pacman: telling you the value $x \bmod r$ gives you $\log_2 r$ bits of information about $x$

Comment: @poncho for example I have: `1091 mod 28` `log2 28 =4.8` I gonna round it to 4, it means that I shall get _4 bits_ of info about x=1091. `1091 mod 28 = 27` 27 in binary  is `11011` while 1091 is `10001000011`. I can't figure out which bits did `11011` help to reveal?

Comment: @pacman: it doesn't directly reveal bits (other than the 2 lower bits in your example, because $28$ is a multiple of $2^2$); instead, it gives you the value $x \bmod 28$, which is $4+$ bits of information.

Comment: @poncho is it 4+ bits of information about `x` or about `p`?

Comment: @pacman $x$, obviously - the adversary is assumed to already know $p$...

Comment: @poncho in my example above `x` is `10001000011` while x mod 28 `11011`, I see that only 2 lower bits  match, what  about other 2 bits?

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming you meant "how to **efficiently** find generator $g$ in a cyclic group?"

**Small groups**
For small values $p$, bruteforce is efficient.

**Large groups with known factorization of group order**
The order of the group $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ is $p-1$. The order of every element divides the order of the group, so the factorization of $p-1$ reveals the possible orders of elements. Using this information, one can fairly [efficiently find the order of any element in the group](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order). See also [Algorithm 4.79](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap4.pdf).

Note: this will also work for small groups as you should be able to factor $p-1$ for small values of $p$.

**Large groups with unknown factorization of group order**
There is [no efficient method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/84475/27100) for finding the order of group elements. With DH, however, since you get to choose $p$, there are some things you can do to find generators of the full group $\mathbb{Z}_p$ or a generator of a large cyclic subgroup with in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. See [4.6.1 of HAC Ch 4](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap4.pdf#page=164). See also [another question here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/828/706).

Comment: I would like to point that the algorithm mentioned is the 4.80, not the 4.79.