# Solving discrete logarithm when p is not a safe prime

Tags: diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm, safe-prime

If you have the cyclic group of integers modulo $p$, where $p$ is not a safe prime, as well as a generator $g$ with which for all factors $q$ of $(p-1)$,

$g^{(p-1)/q} \ne 1$,

[This answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9011/24627) says that given $g$ and $g^x \bmod p$, we can determine $x \bmod q$ in $O(\sqrt{q})$ time.

What algorithm lets us do that?

Comment: You may be looking for the [Pohlig-Hellman algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm). By the way, this remains true even if $p$ is a safe prime, but in this case $q$ is sufficiently large for it to not be a problem.

Comment: Also you can use Shank's algorithm (it needs $O(\sqrt{q})$ memory)

Comment: @fkraiem and 111 Seems like an answer rather than a comment, could you answer?

Comment: This was 3 years ago.