# Relationship between an elements order and the DLP

Tags: diffie-hellman

How can I use these properties to attack the DHKE? I know that the order of $a$ is always $2$ for $a = P - 1$ in $Z_p$. The subgroups generated by a will be $\{1,a\}$.

Comment: Quoting our help-section: *“…please provide an indication of what you are not understanding and your attempts at solving it, so we have a clear indication of where you are stuck. This goes for all questions, not just homework. [**If you have just written out your assignment, your question will be closed.**](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) You might want to read [this article](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this article](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) on writing the perfect question.”*

Comment: We don't have a good question about small subgroup attacks and IMO we should have one. But I'm not sure if we should use this one (edited if necessary), or if we should create a well written canonical question, and close this one as duplicate of it.

Comment: Related question: [Solving discrete logarithm when p is not a safe prime](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26099/solving-discrete-logarithm-when-p-is-not-a-safe-prime)

Answer (score 1):

If the order of $a=-1\mod{p}$ and $b=a^{e}\mod{p}$, then $b=\pm{1}\mod{p}$.
If $b=1\mod{p}$, the discrete logarithm is $0$.
If $b=-1\mod{p}$, the discrete logarithm is $1$.