# Diffie Hellman unsafe prime vulnerability

Tags: diffie-hellman, prime-numbers, number-theory

I have done some research about how the DH key exchange is unsafe if an unsafe prime p is used (that is, $p-1$ has a lot of small factors). Many answers here on StackExchange claim that for any factor $r$ where $g^{\frac{p-1}{r}}\neq1$, if given $g$ and $g^x \bmod p$, one can determine the value of $x \bmod r$ in $O(\sqrt{r})$ time (See [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9011/52979) and [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/833/52979) answer).

The latter of the two answers even includes an outline of a way to do this. However, this requires $A^{\frac{p-1}{r}}$ with $A$ being the public key to be calculated. For a large $A$ and $p$ (say 4096 bits for both) and a small $r$ (8 bits or less), for me this does not seem to be computationally possible. Therefore, I was wondering how one would write a solution to this problem which is possible to execute with finite time and memory.

Comment: By definition if p is prime then all p-1 have a small factor (2) ,)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For a large $A$ and $p$ (say 4096 bits for both) and a small $r$ (8 bits or less), for me this does not seem to be computationally possible.

Actually, it's straightforward to compute $A^{\frac{p-1}{r}} \bmod p$; one straightforward way is to use the [binary exponentiation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

If $\frac{p-1}{r} < 2^n$, then this will take no more than $2n$ modular multiplications (and so, in your example, fewer than 8184 modular multiplications); one could do somewhat better, but this is good enough to show that it is practical.

Note: you use those same algorithms to make the computations within DH (computing $g^x \bmod p$ for large $x$) feasible.

---

Note on the notation (which might be what is confusing you): sometimes, we leave off the $\bmod p$; at those times, we assume that the reader will understand that we are not working in $\mathbb{Z}$, but instead in the field $\mathbb{Z}/p$, and hence the $\bmod p$ operations are implicit.  This is similar to how, in other branches of math, you are assumed to know whether we're working in $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$...

Comment: Thank you very much, this cleared up almost all my questions. However, there is one more thing I am unsure of: if `A^(p-1)/r mod p` equals 1, then there is no k which would fulfill the equation. What would one do in this case?

Comment: @Lukor: actually, every $k$ would fulfull the equation, as both sides evaluate to one (assuming the original DLog problem had a solution), and so you get $1^k = 1$.  Anyways, in that case, you can't deduce anything; the size of the subgroup that $A$ generates does not have $r$ as a factor; you're out of luck; that is, it would appear that whoever picked $A$ knew what they were doing...

Comment: in the example I'm working on, there is a factor r for which the left side `A^(...)` evaluates to one while the right side `g^(...)` does not. Can there be a reason for that or is that just a mistake in my code?

Comment: @Lukor: you're working on the discrete log problem $g^k = A$?  If so, then it's easy; $k = 0 \bmod r$.

Comment: okay, I probably have a really simple mistake here, but my situation is this:
A mod p is some big number,
g is a generator with order p-1,
A^(q/r) mod p is 1,
g^(q/r) mod p is some other large number

Comment: ok I think I took the wrong side to the power of k, that'd explain why that doesn't work; anyways, thank you very much for your time