# Proving the generator criterion for group $Zp$

Tags: prime-numbers, group-theory, number-theory

I am trying to understand how to find a generator of Zp.   [How to find generator $g$ in a cyclic group?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9006/how-to-find-generator-g-in-a-cyclic-group).
I have heard that we can pick random a Zp and for each primitive d| p-1 check wether:
a^[(p-1)/d] != 1 .If it holds it is a generator, otherwise it is not.

Why does this hold? If a is of order q | p-1 then all I can see is that from Fermat's theorem:
a^(p-1) = a^(q* p-1/q) = 1 mod p

Comment: You are actually trying to find a generator of the multiplicative subgroup $\mathbb Z_p^*$ of $\mathbb Z_p$ aka $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$. The $*$ denotes exclusion of element(s) without multiplicative inverse, and the use of multiplication as the group law.

Answer (score 4):

By Lagrange’s theorem, the order of g must divide p-1. Thus, if the order of g is not any other factor of p-1 besides p-1. The order of g must be p-1.

Comment: that's true, but if I understand well you suggest just checking for all d | p-1 that g^d !=1, but I wonder why some people suggest checking g^{p-1/d}

Comment: It's an equivalent statement that you should prove for yourself. Here's an example to get you started. Consider p = 11, p-1 = 10 = 5*2. Notice how g^{10/5}= g^2, g^{10/2} = g^5. Thus, testing g^d for all d | p-1, is the same as testing g^{(p-1)/d}.

Comment: Here is my new effort: If $ord(a)=d \implies a^d=1 \mod p$ then since $(a^{(p-1)/d})^d=1$ the order of $b=a^{p-1/d}$ must divide d . Assume $p-1/d = k \in N$ then $a^k$ must belong in the subgroup of a.. how can I go on?

Comment: Let $D$ be the set of divisors of p-1 except for 1. Consider the set $C= \{(p-1)/d \mid d \in D\}$.  Why does this set $C$ contain all divisors of p-1 except p-1?