# What happens if we choose the random secret keys in Diffie-Hellman greater than prime?

Tags: diffie-hellman, key-exchange

Diffie-Hellman works as follows:

Given public parameters $p$ (a large prime) and $g$ (always referred to as a generator of $(\mathbb{Z}^∗_p)$. Then:

- Alice randomly chooses $a<p$ and sends $A\leftarrow g^a \mod p$ to Bob;
- Bob randomly chooses $b<p$ and sends $B\leftarrow g^b \mod p $ to Alice;
- Alice computes $S\leftarrow B^a \mod p$;
- Bob computes $S\leftarrow A^b \mod p$.

What happens if we choose $a$ and $b$ grater than $p$?

Comment: I'd just *try* this myself :)

Comment: Hint: apply [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Comment: g (usually) generates a **subgroup** of $Z_p^*$, see the autorecommended https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/828/for-diffie-hellman-must-g-be-a-generator?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The modulus operation $\pmod p$ is performed at each step and reduces the result into $\bmod p$. And a clever implementation can use the [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) instead of taking the power than reducing to modulo $p$. After that it's possible to use the modular version of [repeated squares algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) or similar.

Example 1) code used from  [sublimerobots](https://sublimerobots.com/2015/01/simple-diffie-hellman-example-python/)

```
sharedPrime = 23    # p
sharedBase = 5      # g

aliceSecret = 600     # a
bobSecret = 1500      # b

Alice Sends Over Public Chanel:  8
Bob Sends Over Public Chanel:  4

Privately Calculated Shared Secret:
Alice Shared Secret:  2
Bob Shared Secret:  2
```

Example 2)

```
sharedPrime = 23    # p
sharedBase = 5      # g

aliceSecret = 6000000     # a
bobSecret = 15000000   # b

Alice Sends Over Public Chanel:  8
Bob Sends Over Public Chanel:  4

Privately Calculated Shared Secret:
Alice Shared Secret:  2
Bob Shared Secret:  2
```

I think you are confusing the mathematical representation and the actual value.

---

In the sense of optimization, the code from `sublimerobots` is not good. Actually. instead of

```
bobSharedSecret = (A**bobSecret) % sharedPrime
```

a faster version

```
bobSharedSecret = pow(A,bobSecret,sharedPrime)
```

which uses modular binary exponentiation.

Comment: Dear @kelalaka, I think that something is wrong with your answer. In example 2, you said $5^{6000000} \bmod 23 =17$ but this is wrong.

Comment: Two remarks: A] use of FLT is optional, and only provides a time saving by a factor like $\log(a)/\log(p)$ (about 2 in the first example, about 5 in the second). B] As pointed in above comment, the values in the second example are wrong.

Comment: @fgrieu I don't know why it was a mistake and why I did not correct it. I've used code to generate! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It could have three consequences.

1) If you are very unlucky, and you pick a "zero" ($a$ such that $a=0\mod p-1 $), it will break your system : (but this will happen with a negligible probability, and it could be detected) An external observer will easily guess the shared secret

2) You lose in efficiency

3) Your integer had to be chosen upper-bounded (you can not pick uniformly over all the integers, if you choose badly this point (something not divisible by $p$), it will create a bias in the distribution of your keys (probably not a problem in practice, but in theory it's less secure).

Comment: $a\equiv0\pmod p$ does not seem to matter. $a\equiv0\pmod{p-1}$ matters in that it will make the shared secret always $1$, which is insecure; but the two parties still hold the same shared secret. You get $a\equiv0\pmod{p-1}$ using `$a\equiv 0\pmod{p-1}$`.

Comment: you are alright about the (p-1), I put more precision about "break"